# Why does builder pattern use new keyword though its constructor is private?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am seeing the code [Java Builder Pattern](https://github.com/marhan/effective-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/effectivejava/examples/chapter02/item02/builder/NutritionFacts.java). All things are good except below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                NutritionFacts cocaCola = new NutritionFacts.Builder(240, 8)
                                .calories(100).sodium(35).carbohydrate(27).build();
        }
```

`NutritionFacts` constructor is private and `Builder` inner class is static. So we can access this class using `NutritionFacts.Builder` but why does it uses **new keyword** like `new NutritionFacts.Builder(240, 8)`?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `new NutritionFacts.Builder()` creates a new instance of the `Builder` class, not `NutritionFacts` therefore the constructor of the NutritionFacts is irrelevant (it can be private, protected, public, package level)
- `Builder` is a static class defined inside `NutritionFacts` therefore you do not need an instance of `NutritionFacts` to create a new instance of the `Builder` class and `Builder` can call any of the constructors of its top level class (private, protected, public, package level)

Answer (score 1):

"... if the member or constructor is declared private, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor." ([JLS §6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1))

That means also the nested class, that is *within the body of the top level class*, has access to their *private members and constructors*. That is, in fact, one of the main reasons you might want to use a nested class in your code.

Comment: By *inner* you mean *nested*.

Comment: In fact, the nested class *does* have access to the the enclosing class's private instance members. There is just no implicit instance of the enclosing class which would always be present.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, yes, but not the _static_ nested class.

Comment: *All* nested classes, including static ones. Try it and see.

Comment: Minimal example: `class A { private int i; static class B { int x(A a) { return a.i; }}}`